# Bootstrap - datesDisabled array of dates and Sunday & Saturday

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I want to disable array of dates and sunday and saturday.. My array of dates **work** perfect, but business logic need to disable sunday and saturday.. How to do this?

This is my code for array of dates:

```
function checkDateFromForEvent() {
var datesForDisable = new Array();

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var eventsList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Events");
var camlCheckQry = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
var items = eventsList.getItems(camlCheckQry);

clientContext.load(items, "Include(EventDate)");

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

function successHandler() {
    if (items.get_count() > 0) {
        var iEnum = items.getEnumerator();
        while (iEnum.moveNext()) {
            var item = iEnum.get_current();
            datesForDisable.push(moment(item.get_item("EventDate")).format("DD-MM-YYYY"))
        }
    }

    $("#holidayDateFrom").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        language: 'bg',
        weekStart: 1,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        datesDisabled: datesForDisable
    })
```

I want to insert in datesDisable paremeter, sunday and saturday..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can use [beforeShowDay](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday) hook

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        language: 'bg',
        weekStart: 1,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        //datesDisabled: datesForDisable,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
        beforeShowDay:function(currentDate){
        var dayNr = currentDate.getDay();
           if (dayNr==0  ||  dayNr==6){//you can  condition this with your  own logic
                        return false;
                }
            return true;    
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you insert my array as parameter in function, and foreach every element ?

Comment: function(datesForDisable)

Comment: you can access your array through the function's scope

Answer (score 0):

Use `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]`

```
$("#holidayDateFrom").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        language: 'bg',
        weekStart: 1,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        datesDisabled: datesForDisable,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
    })
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vj77M/362/)

Comment: Yes but with this a fixed daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6], because my company have Saturday work day

Comment: I need to activate dates

Comment: I need to disable all satudays and sundays where is not working for my company... Because my company work in saturday...

Comment: I need to skip to insert all dates(for sunday and saturday) in my table - Events